# Quickly read XML files and save to tables on disk with auto field mapping

Tags: c#, xml, datatable

How to quickly read XML files and save to a strongly typed tables on disk with auto field mapping (MS Access or SQL server 2012).

**Ideas / wants:**

1. Using c# 4.0 and .NET 4.0 and SQL server 2012 and MS Access
2. Import xml data based on auto field mapping (field name and field type)
   from XML to table(s). I have XSD. just add new rows no key matching.
3. Can override field and type mapping when desired (haven’t decided
   whether to hard code that or use a template/mapping file so I don’t
   have to recompile)
4. I can duplicate field mapping if desired (1 xml field to many table
   fields)
5. Low maintainability of code / setup is more important than
   import/transform speed – but nice to know all options if needed
6. 3rd party solutions may be acceptable

**Will this method be fast enough or is there a better method?**

Step 1: Read xml into a class ( c# class was auto generated from XSD.exe tool)

```
ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyTypeData));
MyTypeData data;
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(XMLFullPath))
{
  data = (MyTypeData)ser.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Step 2: Save class to a strongly typed DataSet DataTable (in-memory table) using generics somehow  (like method below)

```
public static DataTable CreateEmptyDataTable(MyTypeData data)
// Creates empty DataTable
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    foreach (PropertyInfo info in data.GetProperties())
    {
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(info.Name, info.PropertyType));   
    }

    return dt;
}
```

Step 3: Populate table on disk where DataTable field names are same as XML names where field types are the same. Skip xml element names not in table.  Just add new rows and do not worry about key matching for now.  Update rows based on key matching could be added later.

Step 4: Add custom source to dest field mapping :  (how - what is best way?)

Comment: do you have the xsd files available from the xml files?

Answer (score 1):

In case you have the xsd files from the xml files, you might want to try xsd2code which is a codeplex project. [See here](http://xsd2code.codeplex.com/). This makes classes within your code based on the Xsd format.

For me this allowed me to create xml code very easily with very few problems. When the xml scheme changes you can just update the code to generate the new classes.

Very nice and neat, although, this is ofcourse personal preference.

Comment: Thanks.  I have VS 2010 will that add-in work? I have been generating c# classes from xsd.exe tool. What does xsd2code give me that I don't already have with regards to above?

Comment: it allows you to program towards the nodes as classes. So you are not working anymore with the serializers etc. That's all being done for you. to give a simple example. It's freeware, so you can play but not have to pay ;)

Comment: @FlorisPrijit   I think this is exactly what I already do in VS 2010 without that add-in.  The xsd.exe tool generates a C# class from the XSD file so I can get at the xml data like this.   <className>.<propertyname>.  This is built-in.  I fail to see what is different in what you are telling me.  The Xmlserializer uses the c# class file based off the xsd to populate the class for me.  Are you saying it just saves me the step of calling serialize or deserialize?  One line of code?

Comment: it adds a lot more functionality than just that, best way is just to go to the site and see for yourself wether you think the functionality would solve those 5 ideas / wants you mentioned. That's the best I can help you with.